# jQuery pseudo-selector ":not" IE7 not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Using Firebug Lite in IE 7, with jQuery 1.4.4. I'm trying to grab all the ".step" `<div/>` elements that are not the first one (there are 2 or 3 now, but assume an arbitrary amount of steps). Works in FF and Webkit, but noticed the same selector of `:not` with `:first` does not select the same items in IE7. jQuery bug? Should this work? Can you suggest an alternative way to select these items?

```
# Firebug Lite console
>>> $('.step')
[div#step_1.step, div#step_2.step, div#step_3.step]
>>> $('.step:first')
[div#step_1.step]
>>> $('.step:not(:first)')
[div#step_1.step, div#step_2.step, div#step_3.step]
```

Comment: jQuery's selectors should work independently from the browser. Strange.

Comment: have u tried to use `$('.step').not(':first');` or try `eq(0)` instead of `:first`

Comment: Could you make a test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: the only way it *didn't* work properly, with a JS Fiddle, was if the `:` was omitted from the start of the `:first` selector. You're sure there were no typos? Though admittedly I don't have IE available to test with...

Comment: Val: I tried using `.not()` over `:not` but had the syntax wrong, thanks for the pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer to the IE7 issue, but it is a workaround, and probably a better way to do it overall.

Instead of:

```
$('.step:not(:first)')
```

do this:

```
$('.step').slice(1);
```

Now you're using a simple selector that is valid for `querySelectorAll`, and simply paring it down to all but the first match.

Overall it should perform better for you.

---

**EDIT:**

There does seem to be an open bug with regard to `:not(:first)` in IE 7.

Here's the link: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4028

Comment: I'm wondering whether modern browsers really can handle the ":not()" pseudo-class in "querySelectorAll()" and that perhaps the semantics differ from what Sizzle does "manually".

Comment: @Pointy: `:not()` is valid for `qsa` if the selector you pass it is not complex. But `:first` is not a valid selector at all, so we know Sizzle is definitely being used in all browsers when you use `:first`.

Comment: ah good point.  Well it's a mystery. I'm firing up my XP VM so I can try it in IE :-)

Comment: @Pointy: You're dedicated. :o)

Comment: Here is a test case I started, thought it seems to strip out Firebug Lite inside the IE conditional comment? (or outside of it) http://jsbin.com/epumo4/7/edit    I did investigate using .not() as Val points out above, which works for me. I like it a little better than slice(), but that would work too. Thanks all!

Comment: @Andy: I see there have been some bugs in the past relating to `:not(:first)`. [Here's one.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4028) Even though it was filed 2 years ago, it was changed to an *open* bug report just 3 months ago, so it does seem to still be relevant. I'm guessing your issue is related. I'll add that to my answer. With regard to `.slice()`, I use that for performance reasons. Using `.not(':first')`, you're applying a custom filter to each element, whereas `.slice()` simply reduces the set without the need for a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('.step:gt(0)')
```

don't have an IE7 handy to test at the moment though

Answer (score 0):

The .not() method is recommended over the :not pseudo-class selector in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) for readability, but :not also has terrible performance consequences.  Omitting tag-names does as well in many cases. Testing in IE8, I found the .not() method about thirty-four times faster than the :not pseudo-class selector.

I concur with user113716 that the .slice method is probably best here, but for those having trouble with :not in a similar situation, I would suggest something like this:

```
$('div.step').not('div:first')
```